# How to find non-destroyed but GC'ed Javascript objects in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have an application with some objects (of type `BaseTexture`) on which an explicit `destroy` function should be called when they aren't of any more use. [Otherwise they might leak some memory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250052/are-webgltextures-garbage-collected) This should be done before they are garbage collected (and obviously only can be done then), but it doesn't always happen.

In Java I would detect and log this using `finalize`, but such a thing does not exist in Javascript.

Can I detect this in Chrome (or in another browser)? I don't really care if it's buggy, requires flags, can only log a simple message, etc, as long as it works during development. The fact that a `BaseTexture` has been destroyed can be retrieved from its `source` property.

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose of this is to check for memory leaks, then why cant you just run a chrome profile instead?

The `Object allocation tracker` can be used to find memory leaks at runtime, also the `heap profiler` can analyze memory graphs and compare snapshots to discover what objects are not being cleaned up by the gc.

Also the `timeline memory view` can help identify if you are forcing garbage collection too often by allocating too often (if thats of interest)

For more info, see:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Also not sure if its helpful, but if you want to look at memory stats then you can enable memory info in chrome by running with the `--enable-memory-info` param, then you have access to window vars:

```
window.performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit
window.performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize
window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
```